# In jmeter how to add custom percentage line through command line

Tags: jmeter

In jmeter how to add custom percentage line like 90%, 95%, 80% etc fields in aggregate report currently only 90% comes.

Answer (score 1):

the above properties should be added to reportgenerator.properties and user.properties files not to jmeter.properties

Answer (score 0):

1. As i can find that aggregate report will have 90%,95% and 99% , by default. Please check with version of Apache_jmeter2.13 updated and see.
         2. If you are looking for output results to save just click on save Table Data , which will save all data records as it is displaying after script stop threads.

Answer (score 0):

Defaults are 90, 95 and 99%. You can change these values in jmeter.properties file. It has separate section that contains appropriate parameters:

```
aggregate_rpt_pct1=90
aggregate_rpt_pct2=95
aggregate_rpt_pct3=99
```